# solana wallet adapter making ~30 getBlockHeight calls

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I'm using the solana wallet adapter for React, as well as a quicknode free rpc, on mainnet.

```
//send total trasnaction
    const {
      context: { slot: minContextSlot },
      value: { blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight }
    } = await connection.getLatestBlockhashAndContext();

    const signature = await wallet.sendTransaction(transaction, connection, { minContextSlot });
    
    var sigStatus = await connection.getSignatureStatus(signature);
    if(sigStatus.value == null){ //non-null value should mean the transaction was already finalized and doesn't need confirmation
      var confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction({ blockhash, lastValidBlockHeight, signature });
    }
```

Running this code makes about 30 getBlockHeight calls, and takes a while to finish, and is delaying the display of the txhash. Is there anything I can do to improve the speed of this code? Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're confirming a transaction, that will inevitably call `getBlockHeight` to check that the transaction's blockhash hasn't expired.

This may be taking a long time because of the commitment level on your connection.  Be sure to configure it to `Confirmed` if you want to confirm faster, ie:

```
const connection = new Connection("http://my_solana_endpoint", "confirmed");
```

You can find more information at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#configuring-state-commitment

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I had the commitment level at "confirmed" when getting seeing this behavior. I set it to "processed" and it seems to work better now.

Comment: Ah that's good to hear! In general, you should avoid using `processed` in production deployments, but if it works in your local testing environment, feel free